# HighStock y-axis labels changing by itself when horizontal scroll moves

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I have used Highstock.js to draw the bar chart with scroll bars. Below is my code.

```
$(function () { 
    chartOptions = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: chartName,
            x: -20
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: color,
            pointWidth: 28,
            min: 1,
            max: 10,
            labels: {
                rotation: -60,
                align: 'right',
                useHTML: true,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '10px',
                    fontFamily: 'proxima-nova,helvetica,arial,sans-seri',
                    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                    paddingLeft: '10px',
                    paddingRight: '10px',
                    paddingTop: '10px',
                    paddingBottom: '10px'


                }
            },
            title: {
                text: parent_id
            }

        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0,

            title: {
                text: child_id
            }  
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f}</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0

            },

        },
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'OrderList',
            data: OrderList
        },
        {
            name: 'Historical',
            data: History
        },
        {
            name: 'Inventory',
            data: Inventory
        }]

    });
    if ($('#hdnOverRide').text() != "adHoc") {  
        chartOptions.addSeries({
            name: 'AllocationPool',
            data: Pool
        })
    }
});
```

My problem is when i scroll , the y-axis label is getting changed. when first time it is like 0,10,20,----75, when we scroll its changed according to the bar height. As the client requirement is that they don't want to change the labels in y-axis at all. Want it as constant. How to fix the Y-axis label without specifying any max property to the y-axis. As i have no idea what will be the max value.

Any suggestions most welcome.

Regards

Comment: Can you jsfiddle it? Is hard to visualize without seeing it

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't know max for yAxis? Of course you know.

Simply get max y-value in your data array, and set that option for `yAxis.max`. Then yAxis won't change when navigating data.